# Why am I getting a "TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()" on a set?

Tags: python, int, set, typeerror

I'm getting a TypeError saying that the object of type 'int' has no len() when running a while loop on a set.

```
import random
l = random.sample(range(100), 20)

s = set()
print(s) 
print(len(s))
while len(s) < 4:
    s = random.choice(l)
```

I get the right output from the print statements (`set()` and `0`) but the aforementioned TypeError when it reaches the while loop.

Comment: After the first iteration `s` becomes an `int` with `s = random.choice(l)`.

Comment: You probably want something like `s.add(random.choice(l))`

Comment: `s = set(random.sample(l, 4))`. `sample` already avoids duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the result to the `set`, otherwise you are just re-assigning the `set` to the result of `random.choice`, which is an `int`:

```py
while len(s) < 4:
    s.add(random.choice(l))
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because your `while` loop is switching the value to an integer at `s = random.choice(l)`. See:

```
import random
l = random.sample(range(100), 20)

s = set()
print(s) 
print(len(s))
while len(s) < 4:
    s = random.choice(l)
    print(s)
```

this returns:

```
set()
0
50
```

and then gives you the type error. So you are getting the error because `s` was originally a set, then it gets switched to `int` and goes back through the `while` loop and has no `len`